# Is it possible to have a model named 'application' in Ember.js app?

Tags: ember.js

I use RESTSerializer and implement it as default in `app/serializers/application.js`

In my project, I have a model named 'application' and I need to create a custom serializer for this model. And I faced a problem, that they are the same name with default lookup directory.

Can't find any settings in docs to solve this namespace conflict.

Comment: Haven't tried myself but you should be able to use serlializer methods `modelNameFromPayloadKey` and `payloadKeyFromModelName` to map a resource called `application` on API layer to a model with a different name (e.g. `app`) in Ember Data.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward approach here is to rename your model, or to namespace it inside another directory. You can use a custom adapter extension for that renamed model to point to the right API endpoint. You can use pathForType to override the default translation from model name to api endpoint.

```
export default class ApplicationModelAdapter extends ApplicationAdapter {
  pathForType(type) {
    return 'application'
  }
}
```

More generally, the docs you're looking for with respect to resolving namespace conflict are here: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/dependency-injection/. You can customize the registration of your modules with initializers.

Comment: Or use custom serializer for each model. But your solution is much flexible. I renamed the model to 'app', create a custom adapter for it with `pathForType` and custom serializer with `modelNameFromPayloadKey`. It works, thank you.